# Celery task initiated by Django not running

Tags: python, django, django-celery

In one of the **POST** API in Django view, I have the following:

```
data_processing.apply_async(
        args=[data], queue='image', countdown=10
    )
```

In the celery task, I have:

```
@shared_task
def data_processing(data):
   dataid = data['dataid']
   print "ABSBBSBBB"
   print "ANSNNDNDN"
```

There is no error during POSTing of data, but the print statements are not working. Nothing is getting printed on the console, but data POSTing is successful.

**Edit**: In celery.py, I have the following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings  # noqa
from kombu import Queue

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.development')

app = Celery('config')

app.conf.update(
   BROKER_URL='.....',
   CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
   CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
   CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
   CELERY_QUEUES=(
     Queue('default', routing_key='default'),
     Queue('image', routing_key='image'),
   ),
   CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE='default',
   CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE='default',
   CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY='default',
   CELERY_MAX_RETRY=3,
   CELERY_RETRY_COUNTDOWN=60*15,
   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
  )

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

In config/**init**.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Comment: How was the logging for celery setup? There's a chance those are in `celery.log` or something of such.

Comment: Can you post the code where you define your celery app, what command you're using to create the celery worker, and the __init__.py of your celery module?

Comment: @JensAstrup: I have added some settings. Do I need to run `python manage.py syncdb` first and then run `python manage.py runserver` ??

Comment: There is a very strong chance that this is a logging setup issue, not an issue with your task code.

Comment: @User_Targaryen Out of curiosity, what version of python are you on? If this is 3, your print statements may be erroring. Those errors may be getting captured by the celery worker.

Comment: @JennerFelton: I'm using python 2.7, django 1.8

Comment: @User_Targaryen Could you add the logging section of your django settings.py file?

Comment: Solved...I had not started the celery worker!!! Thank you everyone for the help...